# Elokai Neshama (etc) - what to do if in the middle one realises the preceding Asher Yatzar was invalid?

Tags: halacha, blessing

Brachot that do not begin with "Baruch Atah" are generally supposed to follow another Beracha (see Berachot 46a, Mishneh Torah, Berachot 11:1 for more information).

If one is in the middle of reciting one, and then realises that the preceding beracha was invalid for some reason (*beracha levatala*, *beracha she'en tzericha*, not pronounced properly etc.), what should one do assuming they haven't said *Baruch Ata Ado-nai* at the end yet?

In the case that they are not a *beracha hasemucha lachaverta*, maybe the halacha is to continue (what if it is?), but as one hasn't said *Baruch Ata Ado-nai* yet, perhaps they are supposed to stop.

Comment: Note, the example given (Elokai Neshama), is actually the subject of debate, whether or not it needs to be recited as a "beracha ha'semucha le'chaverta". See Tur (OC 6) who opines that it does NOT need to be recited immediately after "Asher Yatzar". This is also codified in Shulchan Aruch (OC 6:3). However see Misheh Berurah (ad loc. 12) who posits that it's preferable to conform to all opinions and recite it immediately after "Asher Yatzar".

Comment: Yes ty, as specified in the body of the question, I would like a comprehensive answer dealing with all possibilities of these types of beracha

Comment: I understand that that's what you are asking. However I feel that to head your question with an example that is the matter of debate, is a poor choice of an example.

Comment: I am actually most interested in the example that is a matter of debate

Comment: That's strange. If the accepted Halacha [Tur and Shulchan Aruch (and others)] agrees that it doesn't need to be "semucha le'chaverta", then why would it matter if the "Asher Yatzar" was possibly invalid?

Comment: @IsraelReader despite that, the practical ruling is it is still better to say it after a valid beracha, and therefore the question of what to do if in the middle is still valid.

Comment: @IsraelReader https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%99_%D7%95

Comment: This is a pretty fanciful case.

Comment: I agree with others that it may not be the best example and/or farfetched. However, it does raise an interesting fundamental question: if you start saying a tefilah (and you haven't yet said barukh ata hashem) in a way that if you finished would be kosher b'dieved but would not be ideal, is it better to back up and do it right or to finish it? As @DoubleAA alludes; another example might be if you started tefilat haderekh and realized in the middle that you could have made a shehakol first and you have food handy and could do so if you started over.

Comment: Even if you haven't said "barukh ata hashem" I would still think mentioning shem hashem would be a factor (in the tefilat haderekh example). Not sure if "elokai" is on the same footing.

Comment: Why is the fact that it’s bracha hasemucha relevant? The question would be the same if in the middle of a bracha one realizes he made a mistake in a different bracha, does he stop or finish the one he’s saying now? Brachos of Shemona Esrei are also semucha

Comment: @Chatzkel if the bracha it is relying on is incorrect, I think its a fair question to ask what happens to it. A normal bracha is not "semucha" so your example is not the same situation. If I am wrong, can you tell me why I am wrong?

Comment: @DoubleAA Is it just Elokai Neshama that is fanciful? Or the question in general? If the latter, I'll take your advice and delete this